# В текстовом файле найти строки, содержащие почтовые адреса Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Найдите в файле (файл находится в сети Интернет): строки, содержащие почтовые адреса. Я хз, я ноль и не вдупляю, кто-то может исправить и пояснить pls?

```
import re
import urllib.request
url = "http://dfedorov.spb.ru/python/files/mbox-short.txt"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as webpage:
    for line in webpage:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        
        url_pattern = r'http://[\S]+'
        urls = re.findall(url_pattern, line) 
        print(urls)
```

Comment: Я тоже хз и не вдупляю, а в чем, собственно, вопрос? :) Объяснить как работает код?

Comment: считыает код элемента страницы в текстовый документ и нужно найти строчки URL

Answer (score 2):

Как бы вы перепутали почтовые адреса с URL адресами. Просто замените регекс:

```
from re import findall
import urllib.request
url = "http://dfedorov.spb.ru/python/files/mbox-short.txt"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as webpage:
    for line in webpage:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        
        addresses = "^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"
        print(findall(addresses, line))
```

Comment: Все равно ошибку выбивает:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\$\Desktop\pyth\pyt.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(findall(addresses, webpage))
  File "C:\Users\$\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\re.py", line 225, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @Serhiyy edited

Comment: Не работает все равно! Пустые списки выбивает

Comment: @Serhiyy Чего еще?

Comment: Выбивает просто пустые списки

Comment: []
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]

Comment: Решил, только выбивает вместе с пустыми списками, как выводить только ссылки?

Comment: посмотрите на код

Comment: @Serhiyy Я не понимаю твой вопрос, сорри.

Answer (score 0):

У вас регулярка была для поиска URL, а не почтовых адресов, плюс найденные адреса нужно собирать.

Попробуйте:

```
import re
import urllib.request

pattern_email = re.compile(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+(?=\.[\w]+)+')

emais = []

url = "http://dfedorov.spb.ru/python/files/mbox-short.txt"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as webpage:
    for line in webpage:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.decode('utf-8')

        urls = pattern_email.findall(line)
        if urls:
            emais += urls

print(emais)
# ['stephen.marquard@uct.ac', 'postmaster@collab.sakaiproject', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил чучуть буржуазным способом, но решил:

```
import re
import urllib.request
a = []
url = "http://dfedorov.spb.ru/python/files/mbox-short.txt"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as webpage:
    for line in webpage:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.decode('utf-8')

        url_pattern = r'http://[\S]+'
        urls = ''.join(re.findall(url_pattern, line) )
        a.append(urls)
    print(a)
    for x in a:
        if len(x) > 0:
            print(x)
```

Comment: А причем тут `http://` ссылки и почтовые адреса из вопроса?